# MySQL LOAD XML takes too long (System lock)

Tags: mysql, xml, file-io

There are 4 local xml files on my server, and I try to load all them to 4 Mysql tables like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "file1.xml"
            REPLACE
            INTO TABLE `table1`
            CHARACTER SET "utf8"
            ROWS IDENTIFIED BY "<item>"
```

Now comes the weird part.

3 of the xml files are loaded perfectly, BUT ONE of the xml files takes forever to load, and if I look at the process it says "System lock". I thought maybe it's too big (600MB), but even dividing it into 10 pieces and loading each one of them gives pretty much the same result.

here's the problematic xml:

```
<item id="48121384">
    <name><![CDATA[BRIDGESTONE Blizzak Dm-v1 XL 285/50R20 116R]]></name>
    <shop_id>2465</shop_id>
    <category><![CDATA[362195]]></category>
    <price>30.67</price>
    <country>uk</country>
    <product_id>325937</product_id>
    <product_pid>395</product_pid>
    <ordering>27</ordering>
    <img><![CDATA[]]></img>
    <href><![CDATA[http://blah.com/price/48121384/p1317/xml/?t=1392794884&u=238221047]]></href>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
</item>
```

and the table i'm trying to put it into (I've tried InnoDb and MyIsam - same thing)

```
field          type    
id             int(11)     
name           varchar(255) 
shop_id        int(11)     
category       int(11)     
price          varchar(30)  
country        varchar(30)  
product_id     int(11)  
product_pid    int(11)  
ordering       int(11)  
img            varchar(255) 
href           text 
description    text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to use CSV instead of XML. CSV works just fine, even a little faster than XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put all item's children elements into an item-tag. Use them as attributes.

I have no idea why it works but it definitely works.